# Another Volley request inside the callback listener of Volley request is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing an Android app. In my app I need to connect with server. So I am using Volley for it. But I have a little problem with Volley. Here is my code:

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, param, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    secondRequest();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

void secondRequest()
{
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, param, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(request)
}
```

In my code above, the second request is not working. But the first request is working. My question is, Volley can be used to do the request like this? I mean another request inside the response of a request?

Comment: With your code, how to know `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse` called? Pls put `Log.i(...)` inside them to check

Comment: Not working in which way? Is the line containing `secondRequest()` not reached, which you can check using the debugger? Any error messages?

Comment: The first request. Response is successful cause I already checked it. I am providing this code as sample. My question is Volley work for requesting multi-level like this ?

Comment: I got the answer. It works.